# I was solving leetcode problem number 885(Spiral Matrix III), everything seems to be correct but it shows time limit exceed

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

This happened once before, I also got time limit exceed error. I don't understand if everything is correct, why does this error occur. I haven't studied time complexity yet, but if someone can explain in brief it would be great.

Here's the problem [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/spiral-matrix-iii/description/).

Here's my code :

```java
class Solution {
    int count = 0;
    public int[][] spiralMatrixIII(int rows, int cols, int rStart, int cStart) {
        
        int[][] ans = new int[rows*cols][2];

        int rEnd = rStart+1;
        int cEnd = cStart+1;
                
        while(count<rows*cols){
            for(int i = cStart; i<=cEnd && count<rows*cols; i++){
                if(i<cols && i>=0 && rStart>=0 && rStart<rows) addToAns(ans, rStart, i);
            }
            cStart = cStart - 2;
            rStart++;
            for(int i = rStart; i<=rEnd && count<rows*cols; i++){
                if(i<rows && i>=0 && cEnd>=0 && cEnd<cols) addToAns(ans, i, cEnd);
            }
            rStart = rStart-2;
            cEnd--;
            for(int i = cEnd; i>= cStart && count<rows*cols; i--){
                if(i>=0 && i<cols && rEnd>=0 && rEnd<rows) addToAns(ans, rEnd, i);
            }
            cEnd = cEnd+2;
            rEnd++;
            for(int i = rEnd; i>= rStart && count<rows*cols; i--){
                if(i>=0 && i<rows && cStart>=0 && cStart<cols) addToAns(ans, i, cStart);
            }
            rEnd = rEnd + 2;
            cStart++;
        }
        return ans;
    }

    void addToAns(int[][] ans, int row, int col){
        ans[count][0] = row;
        ans[count][1] = col;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Can you please tell what's wrong? Which line exactly can be improved to improve time complexity. The same approach was running, but giving wrong answer before few modifications.

Comment: 9 times out of 10 if you're solution is "correct but runs into time limit", then you are expected to use a different, more performant algorithm, I.e. it's unlikely to be an implementation detail/fault, but you having picked the wrong (suboptimal) algorithm.

Comment: Try to avoid `for(...) { if(...) { ... } }` and use `for(...) { ... }` or `if(...) { for(...) { ... } }` instead.

Comment: Given that it times out even for small inputs, it probably is just looping forever, so double-check to make sure you don't have any off-by-1 errors or other mistakes.

Comment: "*if everything is correct*" - probably not! Have you tried the second example of posted problem link? As commented above, the algorithm does not end (at least not in the first 2 Minutes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will run into an infinite loop for the second example input:

```
rows = 5, cols = 6, rStart = 1, cStart = 4
```

It goes wrong in the first iteration of the outer loop, and in the third inner loop: there the algorithm walks to the east, but goes one step too far, adding the coordinate `{2, 2}`, and then the fourth loop will move vertically from that point onwards. But that means the algorithm doesn't visit `{1, 3}`, making bigger "circles" and bigger and bigger, but never reaching the required count of visited cells, as this one spot remains for ever unvisited.

Looking in more detail at the algorithm you should never have to alter any of `rStart`, `rEnd`, `cStart`, `cEnd` variables with **two** steps. I understood that you did this to compensate for temporary opposite adjustments to these variables, which in turn are necessary to deal with "taking corners". But this can be done in a better way, which also resolves the problem:

- Have your inner loop stop one iteration earlier, so they don't cover for the final "corner" cell -- leave that for the next inner loop to cover
- Adjust the 4 involved variables just with one unit.

Another problem in your code is related to the variable `count`: it should be reset to zero for every run, as otherwise you risk that the value from a previous run becomes the starting value in the next run.

Here is the correction:

```
class Solution {
    int count = 0;
    public int[][] spiralMatrixIII(int rows, int cols, int rStart, int cStart) {
        int[][] ans = new int[rows*cols][2];

        count = 0; // Reset!

        int rEnd = rStart+1;
        int cEnd = cStart+1;

        while(count<rows*cols){
            for(int i = cStart; i < cEnd && count<rows*cols; i++){ // Stop one iteration earlier
                if(i<cols && i>=0 && rStart>=0 && rStart<rows) addToAns(ans, rStart, i);
            }
            cStart--; // One unit only
            for(int i = rStart; i < rEnd && count<rows*cols; i++){ // Stop one iteration earlier
                if(i<rows && i>=0 && cEnd>=0 && cEnd<cols) addToAns(ans, i, cEnd);
            }
            rStart--; // One unit only
            for(int i = cEnd; i > cStart && count<rows*cols; i--) { // Stop one iteration earlier
                if(i>=0 && i<cols && rEnd>=0 && rEnd<rows) addToAns(ans, rEnd, i);
            }
            cEnd++; // One unit only
            for(int i = rEnd; i > rStart && count<rows*cols; i--){ // Stop one iteration earlier
                if(i>=0 && i<rows && cStart>=0 && cStart<cols) addToAns(ans, i, cStart);
            }
            rEnd++;  // One unit only
        }
        return ans;
    }

    void addToAns(int[][] ans, int row, int col){
        ans[count][0] = row;
        ans[count][1] = col;
        count++;
    }
}
```

#### Other remarks

While this solves the immediate issue, there are several ways this code could be improved:

- `addAns` could itself verify whether the coordinates are valid, and so you would replace the four `if` conditions by just one.
- By careful loop conditions you could even avoid having to check the validity of the coordinates with a separate `if`. You could avoid starting an inner loop when the line it is supposed to traverse is completely out of range. This can save a lot of iterations.
- There should be no need to have a non-local `count` variable. To achieve that, pass `ans[count]` to `addAns` instead of `ans`. You can then also increment `count` at the same time.

Here is how it could look with those remarks taken into account:

```
class Solution {
    public int[][] spiralMatrixIII(int rows, int cols, int rStart, int cStart) {
        int size = rows*cols;
        int[][] ans = new int[size][2];
        int rEnd = rStart+1;
        int cEnd = cStart+1;
        int count = 0;

        while (true) { // We will exit the loop with a return statement
            if (rStart >= 0) { // Skip entirely if row out of range
                for(int c = Math.max(cStart, 0); c < cEnd; c++){ // Stop one iteration earlier
                    addToAns(ans[count++], rStart, c);
                    if (count >= size) return ans;
                }
            }
            if (cStart >= 0) cStart--;  // One unit only and don't move it when already out of range
            if (cEnd < cols) { // Skip entirely if column out of range
                for(int r = Math.max(0, rStart); r < rEnd; r++){
                    addToAns(ans[count++], r, cEnd);
                    if (count >= size) return ans;
                }
            }
            if (rStart >= 0) rStart--;  // One unit only and don't move it when already out of range
            if (rEnd < rows) { // Skip entirely if row out of range
                for(int c = Math.min(cEnd, cols - 1); c > cStart; c--) { // Stop one iteration earlier
                    addToAns(ans[count++], rEnd, c);
                    if (count >= size) return ans;
                }
            }
            if (cEnd < cols) cEnd++;  // One unit only and don't move it when already out of range
            if (cStart >= 0) { // Skip entirely if column out of range
                for(int r = Math.min(rEnd, rows - 1); r > rStart; r--){ // Stop one iteration earlier
                    addToAns(ans[count++], r, cStart);
                    if (count >= size) return ans;
                }
            }
            if (rEnd < rows) rEnd++;  // One unit only and don't move it when already out of range
        }
    }

    void addToAns(int[] ans, int row, int col){
        ans[0] = row;
        ans[1] = col;
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful explanation. Thanks for it.
Also can you please explain is there any perk of exiting the while loop with a return statement. For that you have added 4 if cases, I guess one return would be better at the end. But yes you also avoided checking the same condition in for loop. 
Please explain your take on this